# Create NAS storage with DD-WRT

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, router, nas, dd-wrt

I'm super confused about this. I'm trying to create NAS with DD-WRT such that i can have various files as well as various users, each user with certain permissions. Some files will be accessible only to certain users. This was pretty straightforward with the custom firmware of my Linksys E3000 but with DD-WRT i find it very confusing. MY firmware version is  **DD-WRT v24-sp2 (12/24/10) big** and the interface for the NAS is the image attached to this post. Please how do i achieve this?

I've formatted my hard drive to three partitions: Optware(ext3), Swap(linux-swap) and Data(ext3).

Thanks

[image: File Sharing Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, i found that the build i'm using is very old and that newer dd-wrt builds allow for user permissions. So a solution is to upgrade to newer build (An nv60k build to be precise).

Also note that to upgrade to an nv60k build you must first flash an post svn16773 build. Read more: [E3000 Wiki Page](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_E3000)